# Date input format?

Tags: python, date, input

I have code like this:

```
import time
import datetime
def dates():
    date1 = str(input('Date start: '))
    try:
        dt_start = datetime.strptime(date1, '%d, %m, %Y')
    except ValueError:
        print ("Incorrect format")
    date2 = str(input('Date end: '))
    try:
        dt_end = datetime.strptime(date2, '%d, %m, %Y')
    except ValueError:
        print ("Incorrect format")
    if date1 > date2:
        print("Error!")
    dates()
```

And I want to define date input format like d.m.Y.

For example, when I input "17.12.1995". I got error:
`'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'`.

How to define user input format?

Comment: You want to input `d.m.Y`? That's not what your code expects

Comment: Your strptime will accept the date1 value  only in the format of `dd, mm, yyyy` i.e. `1, 8, 2017` you even need that space from input.

Answer (score 2):

`datetime` is a module, there is a class with the same name (`datetime`) within it and that class has a class method `strptime()`. You need to either call it like:

```
dt_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%d, %m, %Y')
```

Or to change your import statement:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

so that it imports only the `datetime` class to your current namespace.

Comment: I tried both ways, but now when I try with `dt_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%d, %m, %Y')`
I got error type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: @Heo - choose one or the other, in dependence on what you need.